# Center text in CSS wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm a newbie in CSS.

I've created a website in Wordpress and I've made a new template page.
Can be found at http://jobboard.jobsbe.be/test/

I've added some CSS to make the page look like I want but there is one thing that I can't find out how to get it work.

When you look at the page you will see that I used a divider, with between the 2 dividers the word "OR".

I've tried everything that I know and found on the internet, but I can't get the word "OR" centered between the two dividers.

Who knows how I can do this?

This is my css:

```
 /**
 * The parent theme's CSS is automatically included so there is no need
 * to use the @import rule to include the parent theme CSS.
 *
 * Place Custom CSS Below this.
 */

 /**Changing color of links footer*/
.widget--footer a {
    color: #7dc246;
}

/**Changing color of menu links*/
.nav-menu--primary ul li a, .nav-menu--primary li a {
    color: #7dc246;
}
.nav-menu--primary ul li a:hover, .nav-menu--primary li a:hover {
    color: #fff; background-color: #7dc246;
}

/**Changing style Login box*/
.nav-menu--primary ul li.highlight > a, .nav-menu--primary ul li.login > a {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #7dc246;
    color: #fff; 
    background-color: #7dc246;
}
.nav-menu--primary ul li.highlight > a:hover, .nav-menu--primary ul li.login > a:hover {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #7dc246;
    color: #7dc246;
}

/**Changing style menu on small screen*/
.primary-menu-toggle:before {
    color: #7dc246; background-color: #fff;
}

/**Buttons Signup Page*/
.btn.btn-primary.text-capitalize.m-0  {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #7dc246;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px; 
}

.o-or-divider {
    color: #7d7d7d;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 115px;
    text-align: center;
}

*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.o-or-divider:before {
    top: -10px;
}

.o-or-divider:after, .o-or-divider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding: 55px 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #7dc246;
    left: 80px;
}

*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.o-or-divider:after {
    top: 155px;
}

.o-or-divider:after, .o-or-divider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding: 55px 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #7dc246;
    left: 80px;
}

*, :after, :before {

    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Just use `left: 50%` for the before and after pseudo elements of the divider. The word "OR" is actually centered properly, but the dividers are not.

Comment: Please [read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and then create a [MCVE] in the question itself: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dividers aren't centered properly, just add left:50%; to the before and after:

```
 .o-or-divider:after, .o-or-divider:before {
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   display: block;
   padding: 55px 0;
   border-left: 1px solid #7dc246;
   left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact it is your :before and :after that aren't centered.

You should had to both of them the following rule:`left: 50%;`

Since the container of them is already a `position: relative;` they will be positionned at 50% from the very left of the container.

[More infos about positionning in css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)